# Iterate and store values in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame named `train_df`:

| text | label |
| --- | --- |
| I'm loving Instagram | Instagram |
| I'm loving Linkedin | Linkedin |
| I'm loving Facebook | Facebook |
| I'm loving Twitter | Twitter |

I am trying to put the text into a list and put the lists into a dictionary with the keys being the label e.g

my_dict = {'Instagram' : [I'm loving Instagram], 'Linkedin': [I'm loving Linkedin]...}

At the moment, the code I've written to get this done is:

```
my_dict = dict()


for i in train_df.label.unique():
    my_dict[i] = " ".join(train_df[train_df["label"] == "@i"]["text"].tolist())
```

I get a dictionary as described above but the values are empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and any help is really appreciated. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope that helps you:

```py
my_dict = dict()

for i in train_df.label.unique():
    my_dict[i] = train_df.loc[train_df.label == i, 'text'].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by 'label' (`train_df.groupby('label')`), aggregate the texts of the groups into lists (`...['text'].agg(list)`), and then convert the resulting DataFrame to a dictionary using the `to_dict` method

```
my_dict = train_df.groupby('label')['text'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Convert to lists
textList = df["text"].tolist()
labelList = def["label"].tolist()

# Create a dictionary
my_dict = {}
for i, label in enumerate(labelList):
    my_dict[label] = textList[i]
```